# What would have happen to the Solar system if we were to mine a planet away

Tags: astronomy, solar-system

So the idea is to slowly mine a planet away , one like Mercury or Venus or Mars. Doesn't matter why or how. Only one of these planets would be removed.

How the Solar system would react?

Earth will be affected? If yes how?

Are we gonna change our position relative to the Sun if , let's say, Mercury were to be mined away?

The astronomical changes concerns me the most.

Comment: Where does the mining material go? Bringing all the mass of Venus to Earth and shipping it to Pluto will have very different effects. (In the first case everybody dies, in the other case nothing much happens.) Please **edit** the question to specify the destination of the material.

Comment: For Earth, the planet needs more materials

Comment: There are many questions. And few of them are opinion based. Could you make somechanges and stick to one option, what planet, where it goes, what interest you more, solar system or the place where tha mass move to?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Its a game, so you can chose any of those three planets,goes to Earth, Earth is really low on everything and any material is important, the solar system and the changes that would follow concern me the most

Comment: We follow a strict one question per post policy, with sufficient details to answer.

Comment: As other people have said, simply deleting any of the rocky planets would have no noticeable effect on the remaining planets. However, MOVING the total mass of any of the planets into Earth's orbit as you describe would drastically affect Earth, though the specific effects will depend on what exactly you do with the mass. For example, if you haven't already disassembled our Moon (and if you're that desperate for raw materials, dear Luna will be your first and easiest target) you need to be very careful to not mess up its orbit and send it crashing into Earth.

Comment: If you use the disassembled planet to build space habitats and other orbital infrastructure, you can safely put them into any stable orbit around the Earth or Sun so long as they are carefully distributed so their net gravitational effect cancels out. If instead you're bringing the mass onto Earth's surface, it will increase Earth's gravity and diameter and would require moving our moon (if it wasn't already disassembled) into a higher orbit (or speeding it up in its current orbit) to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't affect our solar system for the simple reason, around 99.85% of all the mass in the system is accumulated within our sun. And from the remaining mass, the stone planets (Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars) only contibute a small fraction.

On the other Hand, if you would mine away say Jupiter (two times the mass of all other planets combined) (nevermind where you go with all that mass) earth would loose it's asteroid shield.

Comment: it's a gonna be a game, the player can chose between those three planets. Jupiter is out of the question cuz it's too far away

Comment: Wrong. Try moving Jupiter a tad closer to the Sun, and see how it wrecks the entire solar system, despite 99.85% of the mass being in the Sun.

Comment: @L.Dutch - Reinstate Monica I know. But the question was about removing one of the stone planets, which do not have enough mass to influence earth's orbit in any significant way if removed.

Comment: Adding the mass of a rocky planet to Earth would completely alter the Earth-Sun-Moon system orbits.  The effects would be devastating (and that's ignoring the planet contracting to a new equilibrium size and density profile due to the added mass).

Comment: @StephenG Possibly the mass of the mined planet would be used to build countless millions of space habitats, or build a Dyson swarm, instead of being added to Earth.